# Why can you use shorter keys with elliptic curve Diffie Hellman key exchange?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I am a layperson interested in how cryptography works. I would like to know why you can use shorter keys with elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) than with the discrete log DH key exchange. Both have to be large enough to withstand brute force attacks. So I assume there must be some attacks that you can use to try and crack the DLP that can't be used on ECDH and that would force you to chose a longer key for it to be safe. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There must be some attacks that you can use to try and crack the DLP that can't be used on ECDH and that would force you to chose a longer key for it to be safe.

**Indeed**, there are algorithms applicable to DLP in groups that are a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p^*$, but not to Elliptic Curve (sub)groups:

- A variant of [(G)NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). See e.g. [this article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/067) about solving a 768-bit DLP. That used to be the record before this [December 2019 announcement](https://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/cado-nfs-discuss/2019-December/001139.html) about solving a 795-bit DLP.
- [Index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm), which in not quite as efficient, but still much more efficient than generic algorithms like [baby-step/giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) and [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms), which can attack the DLP in any group.

---

This [website](https://www.keylength.com/) specifically lists recommendations for key size. Depending on <strike>crystal ball</strike> hypothesis, 250-bit ECC (giving the equivalent of about 125-bit symmetric security against classical computers running distributed Pollard's rho) is conjectured to be about as safe as 2000 to 8800-bit DLP in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ (the discrepancy is mostly due to the lesser confidence about the implausibility of better algorithms in $\Bbb Z_p^*$).

Comment: Maybe point to keylength.com for up-to-date key size comparisons?